# C#, clear HttpListenerContext.Response.OutputStream

Tags: c#, http, server

I have a web-service using HttpListener.

I have noticed this thing:

```
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
...
context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

A client in this case receives a status code 200, so if i have wrote some data to the output network stream i can't change  the status code, as, i suppose, it is already written to the response stream.

What i want: after i have started writing a response to the output stream, in some case i want to "abort and reset" the response, clear the output stream (so the client won't receive any data in HTTP response body), and change the status code.

I have no idea how to clear the output stream and change the status code. These two lines below won't help, they throw exceptions.

```
context.Response.OutputStream.SetLength(0);
context.Response.OutputStream.Position = 0;
```

I suppose, what the program writes buffer data into network device after i call context.Response.OutputStream.Close(), until this the data is stored in RAM and we can reset it, can't we?

**EDIT:** It seems what writing into the context.Response.OutputStream takes too much of time sometimes, in some case. From 100 to 1000 ms... That's why i would just interrupt writing, if it's possible.

Comment: You could write all data into a temporary MemoryStream, but once you write into the Response stream, you cannot take it back

Comment: Yes, but it seems what writing into the context.Response.OutputStream takes too much of time sometimes, in some case. From 100 to 1000 ms... That's why i would just interrupt writing, if it's possible. But you answered what this is impossible.

Comment: The `StatusCode` is part of the header, so the moment you start writing output, the headers go first -- and never again. The stream is write-only so there is nothing like position-control, it sends continuously as you write to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either could use a MemoryStream to cache the answer, and if you are sure it is complete, set the status to 200 and return it (e.g. with Stream.CopyTo).

You can't "clear" the OutputStream, since it isn't stored (for long), instead it is sent right away to the client, so you can't edit it anymore.

Apart from that, HTTP does not offer a way to gracefully say "DATADATADATA... oh forget that, this was wrong, use the Status Code 500 instead.". You only can try to kill the TCP connection (TCP RST instead of TCP FIN) and hope that the client will handle failing to continue reading on the connection in a suitable way, after it probably already started to process the data you've already sent.

Try context.Response.Abort() before closing, this won't allow you to set a status code, but will at least communicate that something went wrong.